# Do we evaluate accuracy on cross_val_score and then evaluate accuracy on test data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, classification

Hi if we were to evaluate cv accuracy using the following method:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, random_state=42)

model=RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)

k_folds = KFold(n_splits=5)
splits = k_folds.split(X_train, y_train)
cv_acc = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=splits, scoring='accuracy')
```

Is it common to then evaluate the performance on the test set?

```
model=RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
```

Are there any clear steps that should be involved before going from `cv_acc` to calculating `accuracy`. Which result would we report as the correct accuracy? I get accuracy of approx 92.5% in `cv_acc` and 87.5% in `accuracy`.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of cross-validation is to check whether the model that you are planning to use (model + specific hyperparameters) is generalizable. You CAN keep a test set separate for final evaluation and use cross-validation on only training data as suggested [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics).

> A test set should still be held out for final evaluation, but the validation set is no longer needed when doing CV.

Following is the process flow and my comments on each stage of the diagram -

[image]

1. **PARAMETERS**: You have selected a model and a range of hyperparameters that you want to model on and you are trying to find which model+parameter combination is the most generalizable.
2. **CROSS-VALIDATION**: You use cross-validation on each of these model+paramter combinations and check the k-fold accuracy.

```
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5)

#THIS IS GOOD! MODEL IS GENERALIZABLE ON k-FOLDS
array([0.96..., 1.  ..., 0.96..., 0.96..., 1.        ])

#THIS IS BAD! MODEL IS NOT GENERALIZABLE
array([0.68..., 0.42.  ..., 0.96..., 0.99..., 1.        ])
```

3. **BEST PARAMETERS**: You can use cross-validation in conjunction with Grid search to find the Best parameters that give you the most generalizable model.

*Common confusion - Please DON'T confuse the best params with the params that are one of the k-fold models. Each of the k-fold models uses the same model+params on different k-folds of the data. The best-params are just the hyperparameters you choose either as a range in grid search or manually.*

4. **DATASET/TRAINING DATA/TEST DATA**: Now take the dataset and split it into the test and train like you usually do (80 20 or such)
5. **RETRAIN MODEL**: With the best parameters identified using grid search and cross-validation, retrain the model on the train dataset and score on test data
6. **FINAL EVALUATION**: The final test accuracy (that you should report) is the one that you get after you score the best param model on test data.

*Think of grid search as the exploration of model parameters and cross-validation as the exploration of how generalization a specific set of model parameters is on given data by k-fold validations. Both of these processes help in model selection and once you have selected the right model you retrain it on you original train data and get validation accuracy from test data.*

Please read [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) as it does a great job of explaining the process flow for using cross-validation.

In the words of `sklearn` authors -

> When evaluating different settings (“hyperparameters”) for estimators, such as the C setting that must be manually set for an SVM, there is still a risk of overfitting on the test set because the parameters can be tweaked until the estimator performs optimally. This way, knowledge about the test set can “leak” into the model, and evaluation metrics no longer report on generalization performance. To solve this problem, yet another part of the dataset can be held out as a so-called “validation set”: training proceeds on the training set, after which evaluation is done on the validation set, and when the experiment seems to be successful, the final evaluation can be done on the test set.

---

**WHAT IS CROSS VALIDATION?**

In the basic approach, called k-fold CV, the training set is split into k smaller sets (other approaches are described below, but generally follow the same principles). The following procedure is followed for each of the k “folds”:

- A model is trained using the folds as training data;
- the resulting model is validated on the remaining part of the data (i.e., it is used as a test set to compute a performance measure such as accuracy).

The performance measure reported by k-fold cross-validation is then the average of the values computed in the loop.

This image should summarize everything that I have discussed above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach is to run it on the training set. You have the official docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

[image]

You run cross validation on your training data, so that you have several different folds of the training and then you take that parameters and test it (without running cross validation on your test set, just simple use the parameters from your cross validation of your training data).